# Python code to remove the nested key from a value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Currently I have a nested dictionary with keys as "Apple" and "Mango". and in the value we have "0" again as keys.

```
Fruits = {
  "Apple": {
    "0": 0.066
  },
  "Mango": {
    "0": 0.933
  }
}
```

instead I wish it to look like :

```
Fruits = {
  "Apple": 0.066
  ,
  "Mango": 0.933
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```py
Fruits = {k: v['0'] for k, v in Fruits.items()}
```

Comment: any alternative for .items()? I am getting this error "'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: @codette, According to your example, `Fruits` is a dictionary and not a string. Please describe your problem carefully.

Comment: If it is a string of the form dictionary (something like that "{"Apple": {"0": 0.066}, "Mango": {"0": 0.933}}"). I suggest doing it [this way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/) to convert it to a `dict`.

Comment: it is a dictionary and not a string.

Comment: I have already tried the "loads" method  and it can't accept dict as an argument to convert it again to dict, it needs str or other type

Comment: Pls, I want to see all your error message

Answer (score 0):

```
Fruits = {
  "Apple": {
    "0": 0.066
  },
  "Mango": {
    "0": 0.933
  }
}

new_fruits = {}

for fruit, values in Fruits.items():
    new_fruits[fruit] = values["0"]

print(new_fruits)
```

output:

```
{'Apple': 0.066, 'Mango': 0.933}
```